# What is the field of view for iPad 2 camera vs iPad 3 camera?

Tags: ipad, camera, angle, fieldofview

What is the angle of view (horizontally and vertically) of an iPad 2 camera (the one in the back)?
The new iPad has a better camera, but is the angle of view much improved? Also is there a difference taking a picture and using the video in the field of view?

on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view) I found this formula

[image: Field of view]

For a lens projecting a rectilinear image, the angle of view (α) can be calculated from the chosen dimension (d), and effective focal length (f).

I don't know how to use this formula. If you don't know too, only the results are good as well. ;)